# How to copy NLA strip without creating a new track?

Tags: nla-editor

I would like to make many linked copies of a strip. This strip controls the eye blinking. When I press Alt+D, it creates a new NLA track for the new copied strip.

This will end up having a new track whenever the character blinks lol

Comment: yes, it doesn't seem logic, but you can bring back the strip on the right track then delete the new created track, or, other solution, press shift A to add the action on its own track

Comment: Hi, moonboots I love you answering my questions :) Thank you so much. I would be happy to give you the best answer so please write them as answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, maybe I miss something but it doesn't seem logical, maybe it's worth a report to Blender developers? That said, you can either:

- Duplicate one or several times your strip, it will create one new track but you can delete it later (put your cursor over the track's name and press <kbd>X</kbd>).
- Put your cursor where you want to create a copy of your strip and press <kbd>Shit</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Strip Name*, but it won't keep all the edits you could have made in the *NLA "N"* panel.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to duplicate the Nla action strip with the "Repeat" option in the same track.

Simply select the Nla Strip --> Select Strip Tab (Properties Panel) -> Action Panel->Repeat

[image]